# What is this receptacle called?

Tags: receptacle

My Honda EU3000 generator has two types of output receptacles. One takes a usual (USA) 3 prong 110v plug.  The other is also 110v but seems to take some type of twist connector.  I need to find an adapter to change it to the usual 3 prong plug. What is this twist connection called and are there adapters to standard 3 prong plug type?[image]

Comment: Perhaps this is the adapter I need: http://www.amazon.com/Conntek-1-5-Feet-Tri-Outlet-Locking-Tri-Female/dp/B007577NLU/ref=pd_sim_sbs_86_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=41QnOhRH-2L&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=0NQJZ23B764BF1N56RM9  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 4):

Just what you asked in your question. It's called a "twist lock" receptacle and accepts a twist lock plug. You will find this type of plug at the temporary power pole on job sites. They have the distinct ability once plugged and locked-in the receptacle to remain plugged-in no matter how the extension cord is pulled. This has saved many foot steps back and forth to re-connect for power.

And yes you can buy change over adapters that have a male twist-lock and a 3 prong standard female plug at each end.

Comment: Some twist lock plugs have 3 prongs, others 4 prongs, and not all the same shape or configeration.  Does this one connector have a unique name?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC, look on the receptacle itself. It will say the configuration right on the face. It's probably an L5-20 or L5-30. That would be a 20A/120V or 30A/120V.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I guess to qualify the name you can ask for a 3 or 4 prong twist lock plug. But it is a twist lock none the less.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey  Yes. it is labeled NEMA M5-30. Thanks. Put it in answer answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

With your help I learned that the twist connector receptacle on the generator is an L5-30 and the regular 3 prong 120v outlet plug is called a 5-20. So I ended up getting this adaptor: http://www.zoro.com/power-first-cord-adapter-20a-l5-30-5-20-4fzz2/i/G0860334/